# Solidity Subtracting msg.value or address(this).balance

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity

I'm simplifying this down but let's say I have a payable function called myFunction. After a transaction is made (via React) I want to update the *number* property of a struct within the contract called *myStruct* using basic math. Let's say I want to calculate it as *1 minus the new contract balance*.

```
function myFunction() public payable {
  myStruct.number = 1 - address(this).balance;
}
```

If I send a 0.01 ETH to this function on a new contract with a 0 balance, *myStruct.number* renders out as **15792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457574007913129639937**

I can't for the life of me figure out why. If I do basic math without using *address(this).balance* or *msg.value* then it's fine and renders correctly. But every time I try to involve either of those, I get these wild results.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I guess `myStruct.number` is a `uint`.
by declaring uint you are declaring a 256-bit int that accepts only positive numbers.

when you send 0.01 ETH to the contract balance, you are actually receiving 10000000000000000 WEI (you must remember that 1 ETH is formed by 1e18 WEI)

calling

```
address(this).balance
```

you will get 10000000000000000 as a result, so you're trying to do

**1 - 10000000000000000**

and since uint only accepts positive numbers, you get that result.

I suggest you use the **SafeMath library** to avoid these errors
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/math

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Would it be easier if I converted the balance to ETH in Solidity somehow in order to make that math 1 - 0.01 = 0.99 which is what I anticipated I was doing? Not sure if you can easily convert between Wei and Ether? I know I can in React but that doesn't help much as this is happening within the contract code.

Comment: @JimParsnip look at this https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=wei#ether-units
on solidity everything is based in WEI, so u can convert 1 to 1e18 by adding "ether" near the "1"

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have to use SafeMath library. Solidity works different than other languages on variables.

```
using SafeMath for uint256;
```

Also import SafeMath.sol from Openzeppelin's library, then you can continue with much more accurate results.